# Error converting 2D matrix to 3D array in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I am a master’s student trying to use R for my thesis, but I am extremely new to R and I don’t have any programming experience, so please be gentle! I have a bunch of 3D coordinate data that I am trying to use in the {geomorph} package to run standard geometric morphometric analyses. I have split the data into smaller .csv files for convenience.

I have set up the data files in the manner of:

```
             X1  - Y1 - Z1  - X2 - Y2 - Z2 - … - Z215
[Indiv.1]    323 - 87 - 68 - 323 - 87 - 68 -   -  0

[Indiv.2]    363 - 88 - 81 - 363 - 88 - 81 -   - 77

[Indiv.3]    335 - 77 - 70 - 335 - 77 - 70 -   -  0

[Indiv.4]    359 - 71 - 81 - 359 - 71 - 81 -   -  0

  … 

[Indiv.50]   366 - 71 - 92 - 367 - 72 - 91 -   -  0
```

I import to R using `read.table` just fine (with dimensions 50 x 645), and I can even convert the resulting data frame into a matrix using `as.matrix` (maintaining the 50 x 645 dimensions). However, when I go to convert the data into an array (dimensions 215 x 3 x 50) using `arrayspecs` {geomorph}, I get more than 50 warnings saying that the "data length is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows". I have been using

```
> WM.array<-arrayspecs(WM.mat,215,3,byLand=F)
```

But every time I run this command I get the warnings “data length is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows". I believe {geomorph} wants the data in a 3D array with 3 columns (X,Y,Z) and 215 rows (the max number of coordinate points), and the third dimension is the 50 individuals.

Any help on resolving this would be much appreciated, as I cannot find references for actually resolving this error (at least none that are understandable to me). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used your code on a random 50 x 645 matrix and it didn't produce any warnings or errors: `mat <- matrix(runif(50*645), nrow = 50, ncol = 645)`; `dim(mat) #[1]  50 645`; `spec.mat <- arrayspecs(mat,215,3,byLand=F)`; `dim(spec.mat) #[1] 215   3  50`. I'd guess that something might be wrong with your data, but since you already check their dimensions, I've nothing left to guess.

Comment: Thank you! I did end up having non-numeric values in my first column, which I was trying to make the row names, which is where my problem seems to have arisen. I deleted that column and have safely moved on to my next puzzle with my data. Thanks again!

Comment: In the future you can avoid having to remove the first column that was supposed to be row names, by using `row.names = 1` when calling `read.table`. See argument `row.names` in `?read.table`. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 1):

A matrix or an array is really a folded vector and the rows are the "first dimension". So just "redimensioning" by re-assigning the dimension attribute is really quite dangerous. I would think you would need to first transpose that matrix if you wanted the 645 dimension first so that you could re-dimension it by breaking into 215 x 3 segments: Try this:

```
 WM.array<-t( WM.mat)
 dim( WM.array) <- c(215, 3, 50)
```

Another method would be to use the function `aperm`:

```
 WM.array<- WM.mat)
 dim( WM.array) <- c(50, 215, 3)    
 WM.array <- aperm(WM.array, c(2,3,1) )
```

The second argument to `aperm` is the new order of the numbered old dimensions. As always you should play around with small test objects:

```
arr <- array(1:(2*3*4), c(2,3,4) )
arr
mat <- matrix(1:(2*3*4), 2)
mat
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimensionality of an array is just an attribute. You may be able to go

```
dim(WM.mat) <- c(215, 3, 50)
```

depending on how your data is arranged, and what other things `arrayspecs` does.

Comment: That may not throw an error but it also may not do what was intended. It will probably completely scramble a 50 x 645 matrix. Try it with a 5 x 12 matrix that you know the order of and assign the dim as `c(4,3,5)`